# What are the least controversial doctrines in Christianity?

Tags: global-christianity, demographics

Which set of doctrines is accepted and believed by the vast majority of Christians? To get started, I think the doctrine "God exists" must surely be the least controversial of all.

**Note**: This is essentially the polar opposite to my recently asked (and closed) question [What are the most controversial and heatedly debated doctrines in Christianity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/86318/50422)

**EDIT**: a probably more on-topic polar opposite question: [What is an overview of denominational doctrines that are most commonly defended by apologists against objections from other denominations?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/86324/50422)

Comment: Not that I don't love stating the obvious, but if the other question was closed for being an arbitrary list question, why wouldn't this question be closed?  Stack Exchange has a long storied history with anathematizing "List questions".

Comment: @PeterTurner: `Stack Exchange has a long storied history with anathematizing "List questions"` - I think the maxim 'citation needed' applies here.

Comment: @PeterTurner - Just to make sure I understand the concept, do these questions fit the definition of "List questions"? [Q1](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/43589/50422), [Q2](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/41961/50422).

Comment: mainly from my experiences at the old programmers.se https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/1973  all the battles on subjectivity and list questions and everything were meted out long ago, we haven't had the problem on this site much, but you're free to test our resolve!   I think the argument is sound, you're apt to get bad or subjective answers so we count it as not a question.

Comment: I'd say Q1 is so-so, it's not too broad. Q2 is definitely OK, that's a well defined finite list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An obvious answer would be the bodily resurrection of Christ. This is the common teaching for the Eastern Orthodox Church, the Catholics, the Protestants, ect.

The obvious reason is that Paul teaches that without Christ's resurrection, "our faith is in vain".

Most other doctrines have at least some disagreement.

Comment: I know plenty of Christians who would say the Resurrection was not a real physical event. That would make it somewhat controversial.

Comment: @LukeHill On this site it is accepted that anyone who self-identifies as 'Christian' is accepted as 'Christian'. And no, it is not a 'tiny view' just because you have not met anyone who has it.

Comment: Oh apologies, I wasn't claiming it was a minority view because I had never met someone with it, though I see how it could have come across as such. I will update it. However it seems to me just pure and simple that a majority of Christians believe it. The Catholics, The Orthodox, and the vast majority of Protestant denominations hold to it, so yes, I would see it as a minority view. Also, I wasn't saying that they weren't Christians, just that I would struggle to see how they call a view of a non-physical resurrection Christian. If it wasn't physical, it wouldn't be a miracle.

Comment: @LukeHill  any resurrection is a miracle

Comment: Right but resurrection implies physical raising from the dead. That's an event that denies the supernatural. If it isn't physical, then it wouldn't fall under that definition of miracle.