# What is an overview of denominational doctrines that are most commonly defended by apologists against objections from other denominations?

Tags: comparative-christianity, apologetics, doctrine

Each major Christian denomination accepts some subset of doctrines that are commonly called into question by detractors from other denominations and, therefore, are commonly the subject of formal debates between apologists *for* and *against* such doctrines. For example, a Catholic apologist would probably pay special attention to certain Catholic doctrines that are commonly attacked by other denominations, whereas a Biblical Unitarian apologist would concentrate on other doctrines, and likewise Jehovah's Witness apologists, LDS apologists, SDA apologists, Protestant apologists, Pentecostal apologists, etc.

**Question:** What is an overview of doctrines per each major denomination or branch of Christianity that are most commonly called into question by detractors from other denominations and, therefore, concentrate most of the defense efforts by professionally trained apologists of said denominations?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a brief list

SDA - Worship on Saturdays, and Soul Sleep

Catholics - The Holy Magisterium. Surprisingly, this is all they have to defend as every other Dogma hinges on the Magisterium's inherency.

Messianic Jews - Following of Jewish Practices in the Mosaic Covenant

Easter Orthodox - Bishop inherency

Protestant views are broad. Let me list a few different branches.

Lutherans - Sola Scriptura, Free Will

Reformed/Calvinists - Sola Scriptura, Predestination

Pentecostals and Charismatics - Speaking in Tongues

Hope this helps, if you want any other denominations just ask!

Comment: Welcome to the site, Luke. This does not answer the question: *What is an overview of denominational doctrines that are most commonly defended by apologists against objections from other denominations?* **”The Holy Magisterium. Surprisingly, this is all they have to defend as every other Dogma hinges on the Magisterium's inherency.”** Could you please support that statement. Dogmas are based on biblical support (exegesis), tradition and the teaching Magisterium of the Church together! What Catholic doctrines are most commonly defended by apologists against objections from other denominations?

Comment: Fair enough, I was attempting to be brief. My main point was that since all teachings from the Magisterium are held as inherent, a Catholic would only need to defend that viewpoint to support their position. Now if we were talking about other specific views, we would need to defend not holding to Sola Scriptura, the immaculate conception, and the apocraphyl texts.

Comment: The Immaculate Conception is Catholic dogma. The Magisterium and the Apocrypha are not in themselves dogmas.

Comment: Sorry, what are you defining as Dogma? I may be misusing the term, I understood it as teachings, but I could be wrong :(.